# Check if my Java application was started from Network

Tags: java, file-io, network-programming, filepath

I have to check whether someone started my Java application over the network or not, so that I can shut down the application if it was started from another machine.

The solution has to work on Windows and Linux.

I guess interpreting the current working directory might be a starting point, but I have no idea with Java-class; provide me the feature I need.

Comment: Not sure of your application or what you want to do // If you want the application to only run on a specific machine, possibly have the application check for a very specific and unique registry value that you set. This way it won't run on another machine without that value set. // Hmm, I guess that is only for windows. // Maybe just have the application prompt for a password on startup?

Comment: Is this to detect users not complying with your license scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Why?  If it's for security reasons then you probably are out-of-luck.  If the attacker can create a process on your machine, then (s)he will be able to create a process with whatever environmental properties your program checks to decide whether the "user" is remote or local.

If it's for security reasons, then you should be trying to prevent the attacker from communicating with the machine at all.

If it's for some other purpose, then you haven't really provided enough information.  What kind of "application?"  How does a local user normally start it?  How would a remote user try to start it? etc.

Comment: That "answer" does not help! I have to notice if my application lies on "maschine A" and someone on "maschine B" starts the application. For your required information. I have to initialize a different kind of communication in that case AND in that case it might happen, the "current working directory" will be delete, which is impossible as long as the application is started on the same maschine where it's stored.

Comment: @Luke, Sorry. I probably should have said that in a comment.  My questions still stand though.  How is your "application" deployed?  Is it a desktop app?  A command-line app?  Is it deployed in a servlet container?  Etc.  What does a local user do to start it?  What does a remote user do _differently_?  You probably won't get any helpful answers until you describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: WHY do you have to know, why I want to do that.. Believe me I have good reasons for this!It is so annoying to ask question if you already know that you can't help me.And for more information, let's say the User double clicks my application, which is a standalone java process. No commandline, no servlet container.

Comment: @Luke, The meaning of "started from another machine" is not nearly as simple as you seem to think.  Started from a command-line prompt, by a user who has sshed in?  Started by a user who double-clicked an icon on a remote Windows desktop or a remote X Window system desktop?  Started via a web browser?  Started by a citrix user?  The technique you use to determine whether the user is "remote" (or what "remote" even _means_ for that matter) will depend on what kind of environment this application runs in, and on how a user normally would start it.